# Divide a string using JavaScript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
"Employee Name is Jason Taylor"
```

I need a regular expression to extract what is in the left hand side of `"is"`

```
"Employee Name"
```

And another to extract what is in the right hand side of `"is"`

```
"Jason Taylor"
```

I have this

```
function BreakString(string) {      
    return string.replace(/((.+?)(is)).*/, '$1');
}
```

which returns `"Employee Name is"`

Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed a backreference:

```
function BreakString(string) {      
  return string.replace(/(.+?) is (.*)/, '$1 $2'));
}
```

or without regex

```
function noIs(str) {
  var parts = str.split(" is ");
  return parts[0] + ":" + parts[1];
}
```

Comment: Not what was asked - he is trying to perform a replacement operation here - a regular expression performs this far more elegantly than splitting the string, performing replace on each part, and then recombining. That is why he asked the question.

Comment: The provided answer does do exactly what he was after. If it is missing something, the question failed to mention that.

Comment: Alternatively: `string.replace(" is ", ':')`

Comment: :) true! - i went for the "I need one for left and one for right"

Answer (score 2):

```
 ([^.]+) is ([^.]+)
```

seems to work